# Unable to set Application.ScreenUpdating to false

Tags: vba, excel

I have some VBA code as follows:

```
Sub copyData(fromRange as Range, toRange as Range)
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 <copy paste code here>

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Even though I am setting `Application.ScreenUpdating` to False, it remains at True. I have verified this using F8 and hovering over `Application.ScreenUpdating` (it shows True).

My copy paste code works. It switches worksheets but since ScreenUpdating remains at True, I can see the screen flicker.

Is there a way to set `Application.ScreenUpdating` to False?

P.S. I saw a similar question in this forum but there was no concrete resolution to it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Set a watch for `Application.ScreenUpdating` and see that it is set to `False`.

Comment: have you tried to check if there's any event running `Application.ScreenUpdating`  from all the worksheets involved in the process? Try adding temporarily `Application.EnableEvents = False` after `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and set it on again after the procedure

Comment: Application.ScreenUpdating watch stays True all the time. I added Application.EnableEvents = False as suggested. No improvement. ScreenUpdating is stuck at True and I can still see flicker.  I have used ScreenUpdating many times before without any problem. I am baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and see the values for each in the Immediate Window `Ctrl`+`G`:

```
Sub copyData()

Dim r As Boolean
r = Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Debug.Print "'Application.ScreenUpdating' is set to " & r

r = Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Debug.Print "'Application.ScreenUpdating' is set to " & r

End Sub
```

Comment: This is the output: 'Application.ScreenUpdating' is set to False
'Application.ScreenUpdating' is set to True

Comment: How is this an answer? O.o

Comment: Hmm, it seems that r is testing the truth of Application.ScreenUpdating = False.  First r shows False, meaning that ScreenUpdating was not set to False. Later r shows True, meaning that ScreenUpdating = True is True. Apparently, I can't set ScreenUpdating to False.   Am I missing sth?

Comment: I thought variable `r` would reveal what `Application.ScreenUpdating` was set to. My watch window reveals the value to be set to `False`. Perhaps I'm wrong. :-)

Comment: @xcl107 The first answer down on [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c94932a8-9cc4-452e-bbf1-fe550edb2d92/applicationscreenupdating-problems?forum=isvvba) site is helpful and seems to reinforce what I said about `watch` v. `tooltip` (or hovering, as you say).

Comment: Brian, thanks for the link. Very informative. My problem has been solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue for quite a while, and I figured out something: Application.screenUpdating only stays FALSE for how ever long a macro runs. When any macro running stops, it turns True. You can try this:

```
Sub testApplicationScreenUpdating()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Debug.Print "Application screen updating is:" & Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

- if you just run this, it will return in the Immediate window: "Application screen updating is:False"
- if you run it step by step, and hover over Applicaiton.ScreenUpdating with your mouse, it will show as "True", even if the Immediate window will show "False".
- if you comment out the [Application.ScreenUpdating = True] at the end, and then run [Debug.Print "Application screen updating is:" & Application.ScreenUpdating] separately, it will return true, even if it was not switched to true.

Comment: If that is true, we don't have to set ScreenUpdating to True anymore? It is done automatically when the macro ends?

Answer (score 0):

I use Excel as part of Microsoft 365.  I too fought with the screen flickering problem.  Although my macro worked, the flickering was very annoying.  I tried several approaches and stumbled upon this:

Minimize the second workbook before initiating the macro from the first workbook.  For my situation, the screen no longer flickered.  I also tried the following code to minimize the second workbook from within VBA.  If the second workbook was already minimized, there was no effect.  If the second workbook was not minimized, the screen flickered only once - to enable me to minimize the second workbook.  Subsequent switching back and forth between workbooks did not introduce any screen flickering.

‘

```
Filename = "SecondWorkbookName.xlsx"

Windows(Filename).Activate

Application.WindowState = xlMinimized      ' Minimize workbook to prevent flickering.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```